# Cut a square without a corner with legs length $a/2$, $a/2$ into two equal pieces with just one line?

Tags: geometry, puzzle

This got me wondering on a friends party, where my friend ate the corner of the cake and my other friend and I wanted to share the leftover cake. I know how to do it in 3 cuts, by cutting the diagonal then cutting a corner with the same area off and then cut that corner in half, but how do I do it in 1 line? [image]

Comment: A drawing might help.

Comment: @eranreches Here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut along the line connecting the NW corner to where the SE corner was before your first friend ate it.

Comment: Oh god that was easy, I have no idea why I didn't think of that. Thanks !

Comment: You are probably not as greedy a cake-eater as I am.

Comment: Or cut it with a plane parallel to the table.  :)

Comment: That's a crumby solution!